# restart docker-compose service from another service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have a docker-compose file that contains 2 services.
1 Web UI
2 Backend

In web UI I have a button that needs to restart the Backend service. How can I tell the host OS to restart the Backend service or Is there any method to restart 1 service from another docker-compose service without involving the host OS?

Comment: you want to restart the backend server or the container ?

Comment: backend is a container running a daemon service

Comment: You can't do this without giving the frontend unrestricted root-level access over the system; you don't want that.  This also seems like an odd thing to put into an end-user-visible UI.  As the developer/operator, you need to re-run `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` when your code has changed.

Answer (score 1):

What @DavidMaze said in the comments ("You can't do this without giving the frontend unrestricted root-level access over the system") is true if you only consider restarting the container via the Docker API, but there are other options.

### Restart by killing the primary process

If you run your frontend and backend containers in the same PID namespace, then your frontend can simply call the `kill` system call or the `kill` command line tool to stop the backend processing, causing the backend container to restart (assuming an appropriate restart policy).

That might look something like the following if you're using `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    ...

  backend:
    ...
    pid: "service:frontend"
    restart: always
```

In this model, a process in the `frontend` container can kill the
primary process in the `backend` container, and Docker will restart
the backend because of the `restart: always` policy.

### Restart via an API endpoint'

You can
give your backend an API endpoint that causes the main process to exit
(against relying on the restart policy to restart the service). E.g., your frontend makes a call to `http://backend/quit`, causing the backend container to terminate.

### Restart via a flag file

You can arrange to share a volume between the two containers and have your backend code watch for a particular to show up, and if does (a) remove the file and then (b) exit (again relying on the restart policy to restart the service).